# How to use try/catch to validate data input in multiple textboxes on form. And stop entering data after error arises

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a simple Window for uni that records details of a customer in a list (while the program is running). The details entered are things like name and phone number. I can manage to get people to add to the list and find them or delete them. But one of the advanced tasks I have to do is to use try/catch to validate the input of the data entered to the textboxes.

I have already searched the net to try and find a solution and couldn't find anything that matches what I am trying to do. I have also found that using this method is not the best way to do it. I can actually get the program to validate data easily by using if statements. but this does not get me the marks doing it this way.

I have also managed to get the try/catch to pick up the error of entering alphabetical characters into the telephone field of my form but it then continues on to the next piece of code after the try/catch and enters a new user with a telephone number of 0 anyway (it shouldn't enter any details into the system after picking up the error).

How can I stop the code from continuing after the try catch in the button method? and is there a simpler way of putting a separate try/catch on every textbox?

This is how my Window looks:

[image]

Here is the class for my buttons code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using BusinessObjects;

namespace Demo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //Object to hold details for each customer.
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        //List to hold details of each customer.
        private MailingList store = new MailingList();
        //Variable to set starting ID number.
        private int ID = 10001;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Button for Adding a customer with a specific assigned ID number.
        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                /*if (txtTelephone.Text.Length > 11)
                {


                }
                else if (txtFName.Text.Length > 5)
                {

                }*/
                //Stores the details of the textboxes into the customer details for each list entry.
                cust.ID = ID;
                cust.FirstName = txtFName.Text;
                cust.SecondName = txtSName.Text;
                cust.Email = txtEmail.Text;
                cust.SkypeID = txtSkype.Text;
            try
            {
                cust.Telephone = Convert.ToInt32(txtTelephone.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter an 11 digit phone number");
                txtTelephone.Clear();
            }
                cust.PrefContact = txtPrefContact.Text;

                //Adds the details of the person above to the list and increases the ID number by one for the next entry.
                store.add(cust);
                ID++;

                //Shows user the details of the person added to the list.
                MessageBox.Show("Name: " + cust.FirstName + " " + cust.SecondName +
                    "\nEmail: " + cust.Email +
                    "\nSkype: " + cust.SkypeID +
                    "\nTelephone: " + cust.Telephone +
                    "\nPreferred Contact: " + cust.PrefContact +
                    "\n " + cust.ID);

                //Clears all textboxes for next entry after adding a customer.
                txtFName.Clear();
                txtSName.Clear();
                txtEmail.Clear();
                txtSkype.Clear();
                txtTelephone.Clear();
                txtPrefContact.Clear();
        }

        //Button for deleting a specific customer with their specific ID.
        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int id = Int32.Parse(txtID.Text);
            store.delete(id);
        }

        //Button for Finding a specific customer with their specific ID.
        private void btnFind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Allows the text in the ID textbox to be changed to an int to be used for checking the ID.
            int id = Int32.Parse(txtID.Text);

            //Searchs to see if this ID exists, and returns NULL if not.
            store.find(cust.ID);


            /*If the ID number entered is not found in the list, 
            an error message is displayed to say the user does not exist.
            If the ID does exist, shows the user the details of the person with that ID. */
            if (store.find(id) == null)
            {
                //Displays error message to tell user that this customer does not exist.
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid ID!" +
                                "\nNo Customer with this ID exist!");
            }
            else
            {
                //Displays the details of customer with specific ID.
                MessageBox.Show(cust.Display(cust.ID));
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI: that's not Windows Forms, that's WPF.

Comment: If you follow the MVVM pattern (which is recommended for WPF anyway) in conjunction with _Data Annoations_ and specifying that your binding performs data validation, then your problem goes away

Comment: An integer is the wrong type for storing a telephone number. But.. If you were to keep using an integral type, an eleven digit number cannot fit into an `int`, so you should expect an `OverflowException` if the user tried to follow your error message. The max value of an `int` is `2,147,483,647` which is only *ten* digits. You'd have to use a `long` (and `Convert.ToInt64`) but I'd still recommend against either.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 already suggest converting ph to int isn't write way. simple add method on textbox_textchange of each... Then data will validate when user enters and also show msg if user add wrong data. Instead of validating on add method you will get prompt msg...Another advantage is that your code will simplify.... For checking phone and email you can create your own string analyser method. Because int and other math values have limitations what happen if user put -0000000000 it is also a negative integer...